# Alternate words that describe color

Tags: synonyms, colors

I've always thought words that describe something's color (without specifically naming it) were really interesting. For example, instead of calling something green you may call it verdant.

Are there other examples of these types of words in English, if so, can you please list off some?

Comment: _Verdant_ is just a Romance word for 'green'. English has tons of borrowed words, and color words are among the most often stolen. Every year the lipstick cartel has to think up several thousand new words meaning 'red', for instance.

Comment: *Verdant* ***is*** a colour, and describes it just as much as *green* does.

Comment: Welcome to the site, just wanted to add a comment explaining that this was most likely closed because there is no single answer to this question. The best fit for this question would be a list, (potentially a growing list in which people could keep adding to it as it is hard to think of all answers at one time) which most SE sites have decided is not a good fit for their question-answer style.

Answer (score 2):

Like most other color names, "Verdant" is a reference to something which has that 'color'. "Verdant" refers specifically to the kind of green that healthy vegetation exhibits: "having the color and other qualities associated with vibrant plant-life".

Ultimately, it's the construction of the word, with the "nt" ending, which means it's already been cast as an adjective, and is not usable as a noun.

Some examples of colorful things which have been turned into adjectives that I can think of, all from French and Latin:

- Opalescent (Opal, a gemstone)
- Sanguine (Sanguin, blood)